# Are Data marts sit within Data warehouses or completely separate DBs in Kimball Methodology?

Tags: data-mining, data-analysis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

According to Kimball methodology **whether data marts sit within a DW as related star schemas combination OR are they (data marts) separate(different databases, not inside a DW) from the main Data warehouse** and they extract/update data from the Data warehouse for a scheduled period?. Which is correct?

From my memory the Kimball methodology says DW is a combination of data marts. 
**Does this mean the data marts sit inside the main Data Warehouse?**

The above 2 questions are **related to the DW related data marts** and **NOT every department related isolated data marts which are get updated directly from source**

Answer (score 1):

Under the Kimball methodology, the data warehouse is comprised of star schemas that are related to each other via conformed dimensions. So, if you consider a star schema to be the same thing as a data mart (I always have) then Kimball's data warehouse is just a collection of data marts.

FWIW, I'm not a huge fan of that architecture. I believe that your analytics databases must perform two functions: data integration (i.e. ETL that brings together data from multiple sources) and data distribution (i.e. reporting). While stars are great for reporting, I find them quite brittle for integration. Thus, I find that a normalized data warehouse feeding stars tends to be a more reliable, if perhaps more complex, architecture.

Also, FWIW, I've been working with a [data vault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_vault_modeling) data modeling approach for the integration layer and am having a lot of success with it. It's a bit complex to learn but really cool once you figure it all out.